# How to replace `qemu-system -redir` command argument?

Tags: networking, qemu

I have a script starting qemu with these options:

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 [...]
                    -net nic,model=rtl8139
                    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:1522
                    -net dump,file=/tmp/vm0.pcap
                    -redir tcp:9999::9
                    -redir tcp:17010::17010
                    -redir tcp:17013::17013
```

I want to update the script to work with modern qemu options.

I've tried with the following arguments, as documented in the [manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/qemu-system-x86/qemu-system-x86_64.1.en.html)

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 [...]
                     -net nic,model=rtl8139
                     -net dump,file=/tmp/vm0.pcap
                     -net user,id=tcp1522,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:1522
                     -netdev user,id=tcp9,hostfwd=tcp::9999-:9
                     -netdev user,id=tcp17010,hostfwd=tcp::17010-:17010
                     -netdev user,id=tcp17013,hostfwd=tcp::17013-:17013
```

but the guest cannot reach the network anymore and it cannot be reached by the host on the forwarded ports.

What's the exact equivalent of the deprecated `-redir` option?

Comment: You have a couple of problems here: (1) you can't mix old-style -net with new-style -netdev+-device : use exclusively one or the other (2) I think that every "-netdev user,..." you add here is creating a new network backend, whereas you want to have one network backend whihc has multiple hostfwd rules.

Comment: @PeterMaydell you are right! Properly defining a single -netdev with several forwards and an unique id and defining a -device with that id as netdev fixed the issue. Please, turn your comment to an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: You should write an answer yourself with the complete correct command line and accept it I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After @PeterMaydell comments and a few more readings I understood how the options `-device` and `-netdev` relates in qemu.

The correct translation of the older `-redir` options used in my script are:

```
-netdev user,id=ethernet.0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:1522,hostfwd=tcp::9999-:9,hostfwd=tcp::17010-:17010,hostfwd=tcp::17013-:17013
-device rtl8139,netdev=ethernet.0
```

In a `-netdev user` you specify all host->guest port forwards for a single virtual ethernet of the guest. The `id` option identify such virtual network interface (`ethernet.0` in this case).

The `-device` argument can then define the hardware to simulate for that interface (related with `netdev=ethernet.0`) so that the guest see that hardware in place and open the forwarded ports.

Comment: I tried the same but ssh command gets stuck, any idea what might be going wrong?
I have a linux host with qemu vm and I am trying to connect ssh from linux to qemu